# Set a checked field value of a table with an other field value

Tags: jquery, apex

I got some trouble in jQuery.
I have some rows in a table with 3 columns (checkbox, name, amount)
I also have a field above the table.
Here, I want to copy the value of this field into the amount field where the checkbox is checked.
See in the screenshot, i want to put the value in yellow into the checked field of the table.

[image: ddd]

```
        Assign Quota to Sales : 
    <apex:inputText id="ValueToCopy" value="{!ForecastingQuota.QuotaAmount}" required="false">
</apex:inputText>
<apex:commandButton value="Assign to Selected Users" reRender="allquotas" onclick="copyQuotaAmount();"/>

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" id="allquotas">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allthequotas}" id="table" var="key">
<apex:facet name="header">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAllBox" onchange="toggleCheckAll(this)"/> Select All
</apex:facet>
<apex:column>
<apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="selectInput"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Name">
<apex:outputField  value="{!key.QuotaOwnerId}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Quota">
<apex:inputField value="{!key.QuotaAmount}" required="false" id="test"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allthequotas2}" var="key2">
<apex:facet name="header">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAllBox2" onchange="toggleCheckAll2(this)"/> Select All
</apex:facet>
<apex:column>
<apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="selectInput2"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Name">
<apex:outputField  value="{!key2.QuotaOwnerId}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Quota">
<apex:inputField value="{!key2.QuotaAmount}" required="false" id="test"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable> 
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allthequotas3}" var="key3">
<apex:facet name="header">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAllBox3" onchange="toggleCheckAll3(this)"/> Select All
</apex:facet>
<apex:column>
<apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="selectInput3"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Name">
<apex:outputField  value="{!key3.QuotaOwnerId}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Quota">
<apex:inputField value="{!key3.QuotaAmount}" required="false" id="test"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable> 
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allthequotas4}" var="key4">
<apex:facet name="header">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAllBox4" onchange="toggleCheckAll4(this)"/> Select All
</apex:facet>
<apex:column>
<input type="checkbox" styleClass="selectInput4"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Name">
<apex:outputField  value="{!key4.QuotaOwnerId}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Quota">
<apex:inputField value="{!key4.QuotaAmount}" required="false" id="test"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function copyQuotaAmount()
    {
        $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function(){
                $("input[id$='test']").val($("input[id$='ValueToCopy']").val());
                });
    }
```

I've tried this but i don"t know how to put on the selected field.

Thanks Dev.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYhkf.png)

Comment: We need the html code

Comment: I have update my post :)

Comment: Are you sure that the `$("input[type=checkbox][checked]")` is returning the selected checkboxs? I think it must be `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")` check that first

Comment: I have change it, it the same, the value is copied in all the fields amount of the table and not in the checked field

Comment: I don't know appex :( so can you post the resulting HTML code?

Comment: I think there is too much line generated in html by apex so it would be useful to put it here. I am going in the right way with the previous code in jQuery ?

Comment: See my answer below : I gave you some hints and some pbl to fix in your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, I don't know apex, but here a general idea:

Once you are able to get the selected checkbox, you need a relation between each checkbox and his follow input : so you need to give your inputs a unique id for each one : something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-inputid="val1">
<input type="text" id="val1"> 
<input type="checkbox" data-inputid="val2">
<input type="text" id="val2">
```

then you can use the value of

> data-inputid

to set the value :

```
function copyQuotaAmount()
    {
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
            // $(this) refers to the current checked box in loop
            var inputid = $(this).data('inputid');
            var valuetocopy = $('#ValueToCopy').val();
            // if you can force the id of the input field to a specific value then use this
            $('#' + inputid).val(valuetocopy);
            // else if you can't force the value (then based on your html output), you must use this
            $("input[type='text'][id$='" + inputid + "']").val(valuetocopy)

        });
    }
```

So even if you are getting the selected checkboxs, you were looping on the checked elements, but then you were selecting all the fields with `id="test"` and because all your input had id='test', it is normal that the value was copied everywhere.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've tried many things an your answer but the value doesn't change on the table. I've put some console.log() and the return for inputid is "val1" and valuetocopy is "the value i put on the field".

Comment: So your are getting the ID and also the Value, but the input value doesn't change? If yes, then this probably means that you didn't gave the right ID to the input field : the value in the **data-inputid** attribute of each checkbox MUST be equal to the **id** attribute of the related input field.

Comment: It will help if you can join a printscreen of the generated html code of your Table

Comment: Well, like you can see, the id of your input filed is **j_id0:formid...val1** that is why JQuery can't find it. If you can't force it to **val1** then change the line `$('#' + inputid).val(valuetocopy);` to `$("input[type='text'][id$=inputid]").val(valuetocopy)` that will select any text input with an id ending with **inputid** value

Comment: Nothing happens too, and if I change `$("input[type='text'][id$=inputid]").val(valuetocopy)` to `$("input[type='text'][id$=val1]").val(valuetocopy)` it change for all the table, that is normal.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, answer updated again ;) You need to be sure to give a different ID for each checkbox-input couple (not sure if that is the case, because your screenshot shows only one couple)

Comment: I updated the code: 
// else if you can't force the value (then based on your html output), you must use this

            `$("input[type='text'][id$='" + inputid + "']").val(valuetocopy)`

Comment: With your code, the value is copying in all the inputField and not the selected one

Comment: @JeremyDeseez I'm sure that you setted "val1" as the id in all you checkbox, like I said multiple times, you need to use a different id for each checkbox/input couple!

Comment: <input type="checkbox" data-inputid="val1">
<input type="text" id="val1"> 
<input type="checkbox" data-inputid="val2">
<input type="text" id="val2">

Comment: Ok I understand that all the checkbox get the same ID, but I don't know how to increment the id like first line val1, second line val2..

Comment: Well, the number of column and rows seems static in your apex code, so you can put static values as your id or use some kind of loop

Comment: The number of row isn't static, the value come from a method which return a list based on a SOQL.

Comment: You can see two different line in the screenshot

Comment: if your **key** has unique attribute (like an ID) then you can use it, something like this: 
<input type="checkbox" data-inputid="{!key.Id}"> 
<input type="text" id="{!key.Id}"> 
Do same thing for the other loops (if the same Object exists in every list of quotas, then use {!key.Id}l1 , {!key.Id}l2, {!key.Id}l3